# Is there a way to capture network traces for Azure API management?

Tags: azure-api-management, network-traffic

Is there a way to capture network traces for azure api management when we make a REST API call?
In my case, it makes a REST API call and the request goes through custom DNS to the destination resource. I wanted to capture the network traffic to analyze in case of any transient failures.

Comment: Have you tried adding the header ocp-apim-trace : true?

Answer (score 1):

No, this capability does not exist so far, you have to open support ticket and get help from the support team.